# Php & MySQL login script doesn't react

Tags: php, jquery

Here is a link to a video of what happens or lack there of:

https://youtu.be/IgEeYARXtSI

My issue is that it doesn't redirect me to my protected page telling me that I've successfully logged in and it doesn't record the login attempt in PHPMyAdmin. My credentials to login to the database as you can tell from the successful registration are correct. Maybe, my issue lies in an undefined variable in functions.php but I don't know why it would be undefined when I am defining it. $username = $_SESSION['username'] is the undefined variable in question.

```html
function login_check($mysqli) {
    // Check if all session variables are set 
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'], $_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['login_string'])) {
        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $login_string = $_SESSION['login_string'];
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
```

Thank you for your assistance :)

Login.php

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Log In</title>
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="sha512.js"></script>
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="forms.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['error'])) {
    echo 'Error Logging In!';
}
?>
<form action="process_login.php" method="post" name="login_form">    Email: <input type="text" name="email" />
    Password: <input type="password"
                     name="password"
                     id="password"/>
    <input type="button" value="Login" onclick="formhash(this.form, this.form.password);" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

process_login.php

```html
<?php

include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';

sec_session_start(); // Our custom secure way of starting a PHP session.

if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $password = $_POST['p']; // The hashed password.
    
    if (login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
        // Login success 
        header("Location: ../protected_page.php");
        exit();
    } else {
        // Login failed 
        header('Location: ../register.php?error=1');
        exit();
    }
} else {
    // The correct POST variables were not sent to this page. 
    header('Location: ../error.php?err=Could not process login');
    exit();
}
```

functions.php

```html
<?php

include_once 'psl-config.php';

function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id';   // Set a custom session name 
    $secure = SECURE;

    // This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
    $httponly = TRUE;

    // Forces sessions to only use cookies.
    if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
        header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
        exit();
    }

    // Gets current cookies params.
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly);

    // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_name($session_name);

    session_start();            // Start the PHP session 
    session_regenerate_id();    // regenerated the session, delete the old one. 
}

function login($email, $password, $mysqli) {
    // Using prepared statements means that SQL injection is not possible. 
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, salt 
      FROM members 
                                  WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
        $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();

        // get variables from result.
        $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt);
        $stmt->fetch();

        // hash the password with the unique salt.
        $password = hash('sha512', $password . $salt);
        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // If the user exists we check if the account is locked
            // from too many login attempts 
            if (checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true) {
                // Account is locked 
                // Send an email to user saying their account is locked 
                return false;
            } else {
                // Check if the password in the database matches 
                // the password the user submitted.
                if ($db_password == $password) {
                    // Password is correct!
                    // Get the user-agent string of the user.
                    $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;

                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", "", $username);

                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', $password . $user_browser);

                    // Login successful. 
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Password is not correct 
                    // We record this attempt in the database 
                    $now = time();
                    if (!$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts(user_id, time) 
                                    VALUES ('$user_id', '$now')")) {
                        header("Location: ../error.php?err=Database error: login_attempts");
                        exit();
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // No user exists. 
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        // Could not create a prepared statement
        header("Location: ../error.php?err=Database error: cannot prepare statement");
        exit();
    }
}

function checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) {
    // Get timestamp of current time 
    $now = time();

    // All login attempts are counted from the past 2 hours. 
    $valid_attempts = $now - (2 * 60 * 60);

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT time 
                                  FROM login_attempts 
                                  WHERE user_id = ? AND time > '$valid_attempts'")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);

        // Execute the prepared query. 
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        // If there have been more than 5 failed logins 
        if ($stmt->num_rows > 5) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        // Could not create a prepared statement
        header("Location: ../error.php?err=Database error: cannot prepare statement");
        exit();
    }
}

function login_check($mysqli) {
    // Check if all session variables are set 
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'], $_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['login_string'])) {
        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $login_string = $_SESSION['login_string'];
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];

        // Get the user-agent string of the user.
        $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT password 
          FROM members 
          WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1")) {
            // Bind "$user_id" to parameter. 
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
            $stmt->execute();   // Execute the prepared query.
            $stmt->store_result();

            if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
                // If the user exists get variables from result.
                $stmt->bind_result($password);
                $stmt->fetch();
                $login_check = hash('sha512', $password . $user_browser);

                if ($login_check == $login_string) {
                    // Logged In!!!! 
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Not logged in 
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                // Not logged in 
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            // Could not prepare statement
            header("Location: ../error.php?err=Database error: cannot prepare statement");
            exit();
        }
    } else {
        // Not logged in 
        return false;
    }
}

function esc_url($url) {

    if ('' == $url) {
        return $url;
    }

    $url = preg_replace('|[^a-z0-9-~+_.?#=!&;,/:%@$\|*\'()\\x80-\\xff]|i', '', $url);
    
    $strip = array('%0d', '%0a', '%0D', '%0A');
    $url = (string) $url;
    
    $count = 1;
    while ($count) {
        $url = str_replace($strip, '', $url, $count);
    }
    
    $url = str_replace(';//', '://', $url);

    $url = htmlentities($url);
    
    $url = str_replace('&amp;', '&#038;', $url);
    $url = str_replace("'", '&#039;', $url);

    if ($url[0] !== '/') {
        // We're only interested in relative links from $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
        return '';
    } else {
        return $url;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your form login button to:

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="formhash(this.form, this.form.password);" />
```

The input type="button" won't take the form anywhere. You explicitly need to mention submit.

Comment: I do have another issue now, <form action="includes/process_login.php"

for some reason, it doesn't include the 'includes' path...

Comment: When you say `<form action="includes/process_login.php">` it will submit a form to the process_login.php which has to be present in the includes directory. 

And the includes directory should be present in the same folder where the form file is located.

Comment: How would I have the login form in my root directory and have it access the folder includes from root? I tried ./includes/process_login.php, but it still 404's at root/process_login.php

Comment: The folder I contain my project files is called root. So root/includes/ is where the process_login.php script is. I would like my login.php file to be in root/ so, how would I access the process_login.php file through the form action?